# How to use database logging for a WCF Service application using Enterprise Library 6

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, enterprise-library

For Enterprise Library 6 logging we need to add below mentioned line in  **Startup.cs** for Web application,then only we can able use database logging.

```
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());
```

Same way, where should I add the above mentioned line for WCF Service application to use database logging???

Comment: In the *.svc.cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add  `Global.asax` inside WCF Service application,then use the below mentioned code

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());
}
```

Then everything will work perfectly...enjoy